# How to make evil-mode tab key indent? (not re-indent based on context)

Tags: indentation, evil

Currently pressing TAB in evil insert mode, runs `indent-for-tab-command`

I'm not sure of the exact details, but from what I can tell this is performing some kind of re-indentation, which does nothing if emacs consideres the text already indented.

I would like this to behave (like vim) where.

- When tabs are enabled a `\t` is inserted *.
- When tabs are disabled, insert *n* spaces, aligning to the `tab-width`.

Is this possible?

---

* by tabs enabled I mean `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)`.

Comment: Why not embrace Emacs and its smart indentation?  Each mode is free to set it to something smarter than `indent-relative` and this makes for less tab key usage if it's configured properly.  You can do the same by overriding the indentation function for modes that don't behave.

Comment: ^ this. Also, you might want to check [this](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_tabs_space_indentation_setup.html) article out by Xah Lee

Comment: @wasamasa: Vim/Evil have the `=` operator for that.

Comment: @wasamasa re: `Why not embrace Emacs and its smart indentation?` - when working on larger projects not everyone uses Emacs. There might be external formatting utilities such as clang format, yet - that can be disabled for blocks of code too... in short, sometimes I just want to insert tab aligned indentation without relying on Emacs to do what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have tab work as it does in VIM, use `tab-to-tab-stop`.

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```